# Echo radio or checkbox when it is called when info is in it

Tags: php, input, checkbox, radio-button, echo

I just wanted to ask a question about input "radio" & "checkbox". 
How can I learn how to echo out or whatever you call it to only call out the radio or checkbox when there is info in that field.

If I want to make a form and echo out the

```
 <input type="radio" name="" value="">
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
```

but I only have 2 input in that field or 4.

Example:

```
2 input

<input type="radio" name="" value="">

<input type="radio" name="" value="">



4

<input type="radio" name="" value="">

<input type="radio" name="" value="">

<input type="radio" name="" value="">

<input type="radio" name="" value="">
```

If my database has 2 0r 4 fields in it or if I want to make it do both.

Just asking so I can learn. Thanks for the help and sorry if I posted this in the wrong section of the forums.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understood you correclty, but if im correct, you should call it like this or shting similar to:

```
    <form action="php.php" method="post">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="1" />
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="2" />
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="3" />
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="4" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
```

And echo it

```
    if (isset($GET_['radio'])){
        $radio= $GET_['radio'];
        echo $radio;
    }
```

That would print the value of the checked radio.

Comment: AT SiderQ - Thanks for the reply.  I set up my form like yours for practice because that's how I want it to look.  Now if I wanted to have it input my data to 1,2 and 3,4 radio doesn't show which mean all you see is 1 and 2 with the radio button and the next question lets say has four choices that show all four radio show.